# Excel, extract variable word from cells

Tags: excel

I'm needing an excel formula to output the mineral name from the example list below:

1. Andorite IV (Y: 1954) 02.JB.40a [352] [353] [354]
2. Beta-fergusonite-(Nd) 04.DG.10 [374] [375] [376]
3. Chabazite-Ca (Y: 1792) 09.GD.10 [364] [365] [366]
4. Duttonite [358] [359] [360]
5. Fleischerite [343] [344] [345]
6. Gottardiite [960] [961] [no]
7. Hoganite [367] [368] [369]
8. Koechlinite [361] [362] [363]
9. Liskeardite [996] [997] [998]
10. Martinite (2001-059) 09.EE.80 [354] [355] [no]
11. Nontronite [1,445] [1,446] [1,447]
12. Perite (Y: 1960) 03.DC.30 [360] [361] [362]
13. RosieresiteH? (Y: 1841) 08.DF.10 [1,340] [no] [1,341]
14. Selwynite [373] [374] [375]
15. Tischendorfite [365] [366] [367]

As you can see, each mineral name is proceeded with a 1-3 digit bullet number, a space, the required name & another space. So I am wanting to extract the contents (mineral name) which lies in between the first & second spacing.

I need a formula I can simply plug into a cell in excel & output the mineral name.

Look forward to any replies / advice!! :).

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Hi, I have used =RIGHT(LEFT(A2,D2),E2)....which reduces me to a smaller number of characters. In two columns I have outlined the number of characters which is the used in the above formula. However this is a slow manual approach & will take me ages going through each mineral. I have about 4000 minerals to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data some of the "spaces" seem to be CHAR(160) (not actual spaces) - I don't know if that's really in your data or something that arises through copying from here, either way this formula should work whichever type they are....

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160)," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),50,100))`

Comment: Awesome man, this one worked perfect. The previous answer of "DeathApril" did not work so well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need [MID](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mid-midb-HP005209175.aspx) function:

```
D                   | E                   | F
first space         | second space        | text between spaces
=FIND(" ";A2)+1     | =FIND(" ";A2;D2)    | =MID(A2;D2;E2-D2)
```

or in a single formula:

```
=MID(A2;FIND(" ";A2)+1;FIND(" ";A2;FIND(" ";A2)+1)-(FIND(" ";A2)+1))
```